# Journey Builder Decision Step - Decision based upon todays date

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to create a Date Driven series of emails in Journey Builder but struggling to see if there's a solution to what I'm trying to achieve.

The emails are only suitable to go out at one instance in time. I can see there's a wait until duration option, but I'd need something along the lines of "if today's date & time = April 4th, 11:00am then path1, else path2" on a decision step. Is there an easy way of achieving this?

I thought of creating a data extension with emails and dates, but I can't think of a suitable way to link it back to the subscribers through the data designer

Comment: Hi Elliott, I'm not quite sure if I understand your use case, but why would you like to wait a specific period of time and then check if it is a certain date? Would a wait until a specific date help for your use case?

Comment: If you need the subscribers to inject into the journey at a specific time and date, you can schedule the automation for that journey in Automation Studio to run at that time.

Comment: Please accept as accepted answer if I have answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you schedule the Journey to run, it creates an automation in Automation Studio. You can schedule that journey (or automation) to start at a specific time: on April 4th at 11am. You would need multiple journeys to start at different times for each of those paths.

Alternatively, if you are populating your journey data extension before injecting into the journey, you can set a date column in your data extension and use the Current Date. Then use that data attribute in your Wait activity.